# Wordpress backup is redirecting to my old domain after the normal procedure

Tags: wordpress

I have to make a backup of website to localhost so I can do the changes first the localhost and after on the liveserver. I downloaded the zip and the mysql db, i extracted to localserver. I did all the normal procedure on the backup( changed wp_configs, mysql options table) but when i hit localhost on the browser its redirecting me on the domain name server. The website is using SSL which I dont know if this is the reason that redirects me on my domain name. Does anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change to old url to the one you use locally on your pc. Change the values for the fields 'home' and 'site_url' in wp_options table. If you use phpmyadmin you can do this manually or you can run this query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Also you can set your own url in the *wp-config.php* file in the project root. Just add this code:

`$host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define('WP_HOME', 'yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'yourdomain.com');`

Comment: i already did the mysql script, and i added the lines after the <?php but nothing changed. I can now access wp-admin but if i hit localhost its redirecting me again

Comment: @RafailMavrogordatos Your browser will have cached the pages & so assumes the old links are still valid. To test this theory uise a different browser than hasnt recently accessed the site. Then go back to your main browser and clear out your cached.

Comment: Yeahh that was the thing i forgot to do haha Thank you :)